# Find current of RL-C of AC circuit

Tags: ac, impedance

[image]

Below is my calculations so far:[image]

From this \$Z=110.777\ \Omega \$, with \$U=230\ V\$ gives \$\frac{U}{Z}=I=2.07623\ A\$.

However in the solutions the answer is \$2.4\ A\$. Where did I go wrong?
The answer also specifies the phase angle of \$48.5^\circ\$, but I am am uncertain as to how to find the find the phase angle of a parallel circuit. Is it the same as a series circuit where you simply take \$tan^{-1}\frac{\Im(Z)}{\Re(Z)}\$?

Answer (score 1):

Your \$Z\$, the parallel of the series \$RL\$ and \$C\$ (as you have done), is a complex number. I got \$(60.6+j68.7)\ \Omega\$ for it from my calculations.

Current \$I = \frac{V}{Z}\$ is:
$$I = \frac{230 V}{(60.6+j68.7)\ \Omega} = (1.658-j1.882)\ A$$

From the complex number in the rectangular form we can get to the polar form:
$$ \|I\| = \sqrt{\Re(I)^{2}+\Im(I)^{2}} = 2.5\ A$$
$$ \angle I = \text{atan}\frac{\Im(I)}{\Re(I)} = -48.62^\circ$$